# How to get the value field of HTML Control in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the value field of HTML Control in Javascript?

Instead of picking the Id , I am trying to get the value which is 4875.

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Required" id="ChangesInTreatYes" name="ChangesInTreat" type="radio" value="4875" />   Yes

<input id="ChangesInTreatNo" name="ChangesInTreat" type="radio" value="4876" />   No




if ($("input:radio[name='ChangesInTreat']:checked").length > 0) {
        var isChecked1 = document.getElementById("ChangesInTreatYes").checked;
alert(isChecked1);
}
```

Comment: use `.value`? Also seems odd to mix JQuery and plain js, why aren't you doing `$('#ChangesInTreatYes')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery makes it simple -- for nearly all form elements, .val() will return the value of the element.

```js
let toggleEl = $("input[name='ChangesInTreat']")

toggleEl.on("change", function(){
  console.log($(this).val() );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Required" id="ChangesInTreatYes" name="ChangesInTreat" type="radio" value="4875" />   Yes

<input id="ChangesInTreatNo" name="ChangesInTreat" type="radio" value="4876" />   No
```

To do the same thing with plain old javascript:

```js
let toggleEl = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='ChangesInTreat']")

// Go over each radio button, and add an event handler
toggleEl.forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener("change", function(){
    console.log(this.value)
  })
})
```

```html
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Required" id="ChangesInTreatYes" name="ChangesInTreat" type="radio" value="4875" />   Yes

    <input id="ChangesInTreatNo" name="ChangesInTreat" type="radio" value="4876" />   No
```

Comment: Glad i could help. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

FYI, you are intermixing jQuery and javascript.  Would suggest choosing one type and sticking with it.

Get value of `radio` using `javascript` by `name`:

```
var isChecked1 = document.querySelector("input[name='ChangesInTreat']:checked").value;
```

Get value of `radio` using `jQuery` by `name`:

```
var isChecked1 = $("input[name='ChangesInTreat']:checked").val();
```